# Angular2 failed to post object on Web Api (asp.net core)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular2-services, angular2-http

I've faced with problem. When I'm trying to post object to Web Api it comes as null. But if I use object like this

```
let obj = { "name":"name", "phone":"phone"} -
```

webapi controller get it and process correctly.

my ts class

```
export class Preorder {
public vincode: string;
public phone: string;
public name: string;
public id: number;

constructor(id, vincode, phone, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.vincode = vincode;
    this.phone = phone;
    this.name = name;
}
```

service method that sends info

```
public addPreorder(preorder: Preorder){
    let api_dest = "/api/preorder/post";

    let result;
    let objectToSend = JSON.stringify(preorder);

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this.http.post(this.test_url + api_dest, objectToSend , { headers: headers })
        .map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(res => {
            result = res;
            console.log(result);
        });
}
```

api method

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/preorder/post")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody]PreorderApi preorder)
    {}
```

PreordreApi.cs

```
[Serializable]
public class PreorderApi
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty]
    public string VinCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I've added [Serializable] and [JsonProperty] for model but it doesn't help.
There a lot of examples how I can post data , I've tried few of them but didn't get result.
I understand that something wrong with my ts class , but can't figure what.

Comment: could we see your `PreorderApi` C# class?

Comment: @Michael sure, sorry, forgot about it.

Comment: @Set removed. When I've added them , object like let obj = {"id":"value"} comes as null too.

Comment: There's no need to `JSON.stringify()` your data before sending or manually set the headers.  Angular's Http service will do all that for you if you just give it the object you want to send.

Comment: @Brad thank you for  your comment, but I've seen a lot of examples where JSON.stringify() is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property names:

```
public class PreorderApi
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string Phone {get;set;}
    [JsonProperty("vincode")]
    public string VinCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I've missed fill id in param of Preorder.ts. 
But I can't get why id has that effect.

Comment: because it is not nullable on server side?

Comment: @Michael, yes, it's not nullable. Thank you!